# Vim repeat append something at end of word

Tags: vim

In vim I frequently find myself wanting to append a suffix to an identifier in my source code, and to then repeat it on other identifiers using '.'.

i.e. to transform:

```
foo bar baz faz
```

to:

```
foo_old bar_old baz_old faz_old
```

I would like to be able to do:

```
ea_old<ESC>w.w.w.
```

instead of:

```
ea_old<ESC>wea_old<ESC>wea_old<ESC>wea_old<ESC>
```

In other words, I want appending text to the end of a word to appear as a repeatable command in the history.  Anyone know how to do this?

I can do:

```
nmap <C-a> ea
```

to create a slightly more convenient way to append at the end of a word, but it only repeats  the "a".  Ideally I want to be able to repeat the whole "eaarbitrarytext" sequence.

I have the repeat.vim plugin installed and tinkered a bit, but I don't really know what I'm doing in vimscript.

Clarifying the requirement:  I want to be able to jump around using arbitrary movement commands until my cursor is somewhere on the identifier, and then hit "." to repeat the appending of a suffix.  The above example is intended to be a special case.

Comment: or you could do :g/foo/s//&_old/g

Comment: @Julian That wouldn't catch `bar`, `baz`, and `faz`.  The only way to make it do all of them is to either: 1) match on word boundaries, or 2) include every word you're looking for in the regex.  Solution 1 doesn't seem to answer the OP's issue (he may not want to add `_old` to *every* word), Solution 2 would be rather wordy.

Comment: @Julian Unless you do word boundaries with the `c` flag on the search and replace.  See my edited answer.

Comment: Can you clarify the reaquirement - I presumed you wanted to choose a variable and operate on it, then maybe do another one. You might want to anchor the search to only find complete words.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys; I clarified the requirement.  Sorry my one-line example was misleadingly special.

Comment: Another way of explaining:
You can append a semicolon to the end of the line with A;<ESC>
and then move to other lines and repeat it with .  .  I would like to have the same behavior work for words but there is no single-key "append at end of word" command.

Answer (score 9):

<kbd>e</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>`_old`<kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> should work for you.

Another possible solution would be to use the `c` flag on a search and replace command:

```
:.s/\<[[:alnum:]]\+\>/&_old/gc
```

Then all you have to do is press <kbd>y</kbd> to confirm each replacement.  This would be faster if you have a lot of replacements to do and want to confirm each one manually.  If, on the other hand, you want to add `_old` to *every* word on a line, you can remove the `c`:

```
:.s/\<[[:alnum:]]\+\>/&_old/g
```

Comment: That only works on the current line (which I'm sure you knew).

Comment: @Julian Yeah I assumed that's what the OP wanted, since it seemed like he was looking for a replacement for `ea_old<ESC>wea_old<ESC>wea_old<ESC>wea_old<ESC>`

Comment: Thanks for the response; I'm looking for something more general; I clarified above.

Answer (score 9):

My guess is that the OP took a very simple example to illustrate a more generic problem that can be re-formulated as "I would like to repeat an arbitrarily big sequence of commands very easily".

And for that, there is the <kbd>q</kbd> command. Pick your favourite register for recording, say "q", then:

<kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> -- starts recording

(do any complicated set of actions here...)

<kbd>q</kbd> -- stops the ercording

<kbd>@</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> -- plays back the recording

And as I am myself using this very often when programming, I ended up mapping the actions above to <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F3</kbd> and <kbd>F4</kbd> respectively on my keyboard. This allows to repeat your set of actions in really 1 key stroke. In .vimrc:

```
nmap <F2> qq
nmap <F3> q
nmap <F4> @q
```

Comment: Thanks for the response; this comes the closest so far.  This is more general, but you need the foresight to hit F1 and F2 before and after your first append, and then you hit F3 to repeat instead of the usual "."

Comment: I'm usually avoiding F1, because that opens the help window for my terminal, but that's just a detail. Also, using this with copy - paste a line (containing a number) followed by Ctrl+A can be an awesome way to save time sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

For this specific case, you can use search and replace: `s/ /_old /g`.

Comment: Nice. This is actually what I was looking for when I navigated to this post.  However, if the words are only part of a line, you could also add `\%V` to apply it to text that was previously highlighted in visual mode: `:s/\%V /_old /g`